# How do you maximize the sell value of looted items in Torchlight?

Tags: torchlight

I purchased torchlight this morning after reading how people have been raving about it. 8 hours, 15 levels and countless murderized mobs later, I decided that to get the really GOOD gear for my character I need a good amount of GP.

That was when I noticed when I sell looted items that I don't need to the shop that I'm usually getting under 100gp per item for them. Is there any way to increase how much gp I get when I sell items?

Comment: Just of note, I learned (as a noob mistake for not doing it earlier) that sending your pet into town to sell items takes 5 mins or less, and can get 500-1500 gp per trip to sell off items I would otherwise leave laying around. Also selling extra health/mana potions helps loads. =)

Comment: If you sell everything you don't need and probably won't ever use you'll hardly ever be short on gold.  Off the top of my head I think my journal had over 50k collected by floor 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without installing a mod that adjusts the resale value of items. ([Better Balanced Sale Prices](http://www.fileplanet.com/215098/210000/fileinfo/Torchlight---Better-Balanced-Sale-Prices-Mod) is one.)

However, the **Barter** skill will reduce the *purchase* cost of items at vendors in town. You can start putting points into Barter at level 20, and each point lowers prices by 6%.