# What should I do with duplicate Unique and Set items?

Tags: torchlight

Having Treasure Hunter level 11 has left me with two Dragonslayer Breastplates, three Midas Chains (set items), and two of several Unique items (not so unique now, eh?). I don't feel like selling them, because they sell for less than $200 - even though they cost 10-20 times more when buying.

I can only think of two possibilities:

- transmute them (4 Set items = 1 dull ember, 4 Uniques = 1 regular ember)
- create another character and give them the spares (I don't feel like playing two characters 
  at once)

Is there anything else I could do with them?

Comment: I make mule characters to hoard them.

Comment: You could give them to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Found something](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42542/10744) that may be of use.

[Torchlight - Better Balanced Sale Prices Mod](http://www.fileplanet.com/215098/210000/fileinfo/Torchlight---Better-Balanced-Sale-Prices-Mod)

> This mod offers exactly what the title says--better balanced sale
>   prices. **Vendors now offer more gold in exchange for your items, so
>   selling rare and unique equipment no longer leaves you feeling like
>   you've been kicked in the teeth.**

EDIT: Another possibility is to use them as fodder for the "Enchantment Overload" Steam achievement (enchant an item 10 times). If you succeed, you'll have a highly enchanted rare item in your hands; if it gets disenchanted, it doesn't matter, because you had a spare.